# Random down voting of questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, down-votes, policy

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and got a down vote.

What I don't understand is the reason for down vote. 
Here is my post:

[Figuring out the complexity of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989052/figuring-out-the-complexity-of-the-code)

Does random down voting with out a justification help the community at all?

Comment: You got 1 single downvote. Take a breath, try to get over it and move on. :) Or do you really imply that this case is an example of how questions gets randomly downvoted all the time here?

Comment: Furthermore, complaining about it on meta will most likely just get you more down votes.

Comment: The irony that this is being downvoted.

Comment: That's not a programming question at all IMO. It's plain math (and the answer is well known, often demonstrated in a variety of ways - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn for instance)

Comment: Your SO question isn't exactly a great one.  You state a problem, paste some code, and then do a little hand-waving about how it doesn't work.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's not ironic, that's just coincidental

Comment: @Daniel: That’s not coincidental, that’s a given

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think it's such a terrible one either. Worse questions have been asked without getting to -5, but I guess that's Meta effect for you.

Comment: I have no issues with down votes. Providing a reason for down voting helps the question/answer to be better thus making the community better

Comment: Some community members have gotten tired of arguing with people after they explain their downvotes, so they don't do it anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey unfortunately, retaliatory down votes are not unheard of either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am not claiming my question to be great. I think the user should put some effort before asking the question. Which I did. I mentioned things that I have tried and not a copy paste. The simple point I am trying to make is how to make it constructive. I see the effect of this post in SO as well, no big deal. But it defies the purpose of why we have such community collaboration sites. Any way good learning and thanks for help.

Comment: Not sure you can do much with that particular question.  It's already got an accepted answer on it, and it wasn't closed, so.  As general rules of thumb, you should write your questions so that they are clear, understandable and on-topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "clear, understandable and on-topic".. I did try from my side. I have marked the SQ question as unanswered. Still the question remains... :-)

Answer (score 9):

No, random downvoting without a justification does not help the community at all. However, we do not know the downvoter had no justification, merely that we are not privy to it.

Any rules against "random" downvoting would be virtually unenforceable, so the best advice I can give you here would be to shrug and move on.

Comment: And note @ayusman, should you be thinking of it: Mandatory comments for downvotes have been discussed to death and rejected each time. So should you be thinking of that, please do your research.

Comment: @Asad thanks for the input and background. I will keep these in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Down (and up) voting is how the community expresses their opinion on the quality of the question.  While it's nice to leave a comment, it's certainly not mandatory or even necessary for learning.

Look at the questions that are similar but have more upvotes than downvotes, and see how they are different from yours.

Comment: thats what I was trying to understand. But unfortunately I dont have much to go on

Comment: @Ayusman This might help http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote